# How to deploy Vue.js 2 app and Laravel 5.4 API on the same hosting

Tags: javascript, laravel, rest, api, vue.js

I have written an API using Laravel 5.4 and connected to it from my frontend using Vue.js 2. API runs on `http://localhost:8000/` and Vue app on `http://localhost:8080/`.

How should I deploy them on the same hosting? What should I do with `axios` requests like:

```
axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/api/requests`, {
    'fname': this.fname,
    'lname': this.lname,
    'email': this.email,
    'phone': this.phone
})
.then(response => {
    if(response.data.success) {
        this.showSpinner = false;
        this.success = true;
        this.message = response.data.message;
    }
})  
.catch(error => {
    context.error = error;
});
```

What's the workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your web server is listening on port 80, you only need to supply the path in the url like:

```
axios.post(`/api/requests`, {
    'fname': this.fname,
    'lname': this.lname,
    'email': this.email,
    'phone': this.phone
})
```

You can set a default configuration to set the base url and port if needed:

```
var instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com:8000/api/',
});
```

Comment: Thank u) I'm going to check it and then give you my response.